# R - populate a column for grouped entries based on conditions in subsequent rows of a data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large clinical dataset that I am planning to populate with additional columns and the criterion will almost be similar and hence it probably comes down to one similar problem.

I have so far figured out that, first I need to group my entries based on patient_id but I have been unable to proceed from here.

Below is a snapshot of the data. When copied and ran in R, it creates a data.frame called myDF

```
myDF <- structure(list(patient_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), date = structure(c(17167, 
17168, 17169, 17170, 17171), class = "Date"), date_recruited = c("yes", 
"", "", "", ""), ill = c("no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("id", 
"date", "date_recruited", "ill"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I would want to create a new column (let's call it "drop"), such that, for every id, if the difference between date when ill == "yes" and date_recruited = 3, populate with drop.

something like this:

```
myDF2 <- structure(list(paitent_id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), date = structure(c(17167, 
17168, 17169, 17170, 17171), class = "Date"), date_recruited = c("yes", 
"", "", "", ""), ill = c("no", "no", "yes", "yes", "no"), drop = c("", 
"", "", "drop", "")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("paitent_id", 
"date", "date_recruited", "ill", "drop"), row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

Any assistance is welcome...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dplyr` you could do the following.

```
myDF2 <- myDF %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(recdate=date[which(date_recruited=="yes")[1]],
                                      drop=ifelse(ill=="yes" & date==recdate+3,"drop",""))
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew, it works. Pardon my slight modification. what if I wanted to populate the "drop" column at the row that matches the date_recruited instead of populating the row that indicates individual was ill.

Comment: In that case you would want to drop a 'date recruited' if there exists an 'ill date' that is equal to 'date recruited' plus 3.  So something like `myDF2 <- myDF %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(drop=ifelse(date_recruited=="yes" & ((date+3) %in% date[ill=="yes"]),"drop",""))`

Comment: No problem - happy to help!